# The mp android chart does not work correctly when first installing the application on the device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mpandroidchart

When first installing the application on the device, the mp android chart does not show correctly, what is the reason ?

Here is my code:

```
viewModel.weekRead( ( calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7 ) , ( calender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 ) ).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

        val weekList = ArrayList<BarEntry>()

        for (i in it) {

            weekList.add ( BarEntry ( i.day.toFloat() , i.step_value.toFloat() ) )
        }

        val barDataSet = BarDataSet ( weekList , " " )

        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS, 250)
        barDataSet.valueTextSize = 12F

        val barData = BarData(barDataSet)

        binding.weekChart.setFitBars(true)
        binding.weekChart.data = barData
        binding.weekChart.animateY(2000)

        binding.weekChart.setTouchEnabled(false)
        binding.weekChart.description = null

        binding.weekChart.xAxis.apply {

            setDrawGridLines(false)
            setDrawLabels(false)
        }

        binding.weekChart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
        binding.weekChart.axisRight.axisMinimum = 0f

        binding.weekChart.refreshDrawableState()
        binding.weekChart.invalidate()
}
```

For more details, I'm throwing the layout part in addition.

Here is my XML codes :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Aylık Adım Sayısı"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mount_chart"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mount_chart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/mount_chart"
            android:layout_width="336dp"
            android:layout_height="254dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally, the image of the error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJtKg.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding log statements to confirm whether `weekList` actually has the values in it you expect to show up in the plot?

Comment: @TylerV Even if it is 0, I have the values ​​and this process really works perfectly when the graph is drawn later, the only problem is that the graph is not created when the application is first loaded.

Comment: You haven't given enough information here for someone to debug this or replicate it - you either need to post something that someone else could run to see the same issue as you, or start debugging yourself with log/print/debugger. For example, does the observer get triggered on the first load? If it does, is the array of data empty at that point?